# Overriding Stop in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net

I have this windows service class here written in C#. It has a member function called Stop but apparently its base class ServiceBase also has a Stop function.

`ServiceBase.Stop()` calls `OnStop` which is overriden in the service again which calls `this.Stop()` in its own object again.

Now VS gives the warning:
`Server.Stop()` hides inherited member `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Stop()`. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended

Can I just use new without changing the behaviour of the service?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't intending to override the base `Stop()` method, why don't you just rename it to avoid any ambiguity?

If you want to do something before or after the service controller causes `Stop()` to be called, override it - and then call `base.Stop()` either before or after your own code as required.